# Timezone difference in mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

Here is my situation:

I have a column in that stores timestamp unix time which using UTC in a database.
Every 12:01am on 23/2/2015, a cronjob in a local server will query yesterday's data from the db, example 22/2/2015 00:00:00 - 22/2/2015 23:59:59

The problem is, the db server always return wrong information because of the timezone difference. My local time is in GMT +8.

I've used `set time_zone='+8:00'` but the query doesn't work in php. Plus it is not a best practice when DST occurs.

Anyone know how to deal with timezone difference in mysql server? Is there a way to change the timezone directly in the table's row?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `a cronjob in a local server will query yesterday's data from the db, example 22/2/2015 00:00:00 - 22/2/2015 23:59:59` - does this mean you're querying the DB server from a different server?

Comment: Yes. The other server is my laptop, the db server is amazon's rds. The script runs in it every 12:01am.

Comment: So run the script at 8am?

Comment: I was thinking about doing the same. Don't you think the db server will read it as UTC regardless of when we run the script, thus giving wrong result as well?

Comment: So you query the DB at 00:01 local time when you're +8 hours to the server. The server is GMT-8 to you, which is basically UTC-ish. So what you're actually asking for is 4pm->3:59pm logs in UTC timestamp format. If you want to convert them from UTC to local times try `date('G:i Y-m-d', strtotime("+8 hours"))`